# Specific install instructions for a retina macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, system-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu as my primary OS on a Retina Macbook Pro.

As I'm unaware of the issues I'll face I've been trying to find instructions before starting.  I've been searching for a while and I'm starting to get more confused instead of less.

Has someone got a specific guide that I should use to install 13.04 or 13.10 with (I'd prefer to use 13.10 as I intend to use it to develop software).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any mayor differences between installing Ubuntu in a Mac or a PC. The installer will do everything. Issues may arise later (like Wireless card not working) but that should be asked in a specific question targetting that specific piece of hardware/software.

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends. Which version of ubuntu you would like to install and also which version of rMBP you have. Just like for me. I have MacBook Pro (10,1) 15" one. Install 13.10 is good, almost everything work out of box. You don't have to do any special setup. But for 12.04, I have to do something manually for the wifi and nvidia driver. for early version of ubuntu, you may need more work to do.

There's a lot of tutorial about that. you can put in the version of ubuntu and you rMBP to get the proper one.